# AutoComplete.asmx error in AJAX AutoComplete

Tags: c#, asp.net-ajax

I'm trying to implement AJAX AutoComplete for textbox.

But

```
<asp:AutoCompleteExtender ID="AutoCompleteExtender1" runat="server"
 BehaviorID="AutoCompleteEx"
 TargetControlID="myTextBox"
 ServicePath="AutoComplete.asmx" >
 </asp:AutoCompleteExtender>
```

File AutoComplete.asmx was not found. I'm confused with this..

Comment: Have you created corresponding AutoComplete.asmx service to fetch autocomplete options ?

Comment: well there is a really good tutorial on how to use autocomplete control, let me find it

Comment: Sure, please find it and let me know. So many thanks Vittore.. :)

Comment: Check the video tutorial link of my answer it will help you to achieve what you want..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Tutorial](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/act_AutoComplete_simple.ashx) on using AutoComplete from ASP.NET AJAX.
Although this tutorial uses page method instead of dedicated web service.

Comment: This is great. But also, I need one more thing. I need to fetch data from my Database.. How can I do that?

Comment: There is a whole bunch of tutorials on how to access data from Sql Server database http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/data-access

Comment: Or do you have any other RDBMS ?